# Interpolation Binding issue on IOS (cordova)

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

So i have an Angular application that runs on both IOS and Android. For the Creation of the mobile apps i am using cordova. I have a component that shows the preview of an examination that has been done by the user.

The user can temporarily save such an examination. When he does so, the Date of the examination has to be set to the date of the first examination.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.collectionId = +params.cid;
});

this.store.select(selectFarm).subscribe(farm => this.farm = farm);
this.store.select(selectUser).subscribe(user => {
  this.user = user;
});
this.store.select(selectUsers).subscribe(users => {
  this.farmer = users.find(u => u.id === this.farm.farmerId);
});

this.store.select(selectCategories).subscribe(categories => this.categories = categories);
this.store.select(selectQuestions).subscribe(questions => this.questions = questions);
this.store.select(selectResponses).subscribe(responses => this.responses = responses);
this.store.select(selectReportState).subscribe(reportState => {
  this.reportState = reportState;
  const temp = new Date(reportState.createdAt);
  const temp1: string = temp.toISOString();
  const temp2 = temp1.split(/[- : T]/);
  // tslint:disable-next-line:radix
  this.date = new Date(parseInt(temp2[0]), parseInt(temp2[1]) - 1, parseInt(temp2[2]), parseInt(temp2[3]), parseInt(temp2[4]), parseInt(temp2[5]));
});

this.store.dispatch(new UpdateSelectedSymptom(new Symptom()));

this.fillSectionLists();
```

Above you can see the ngOninit function where i load the Date from the store into this component.

```
<div class="end-section"><p class="text-14">{{getFormatedDate(this.date)}}</p></div>
```

This is how the date should be displayed, using an interpolation binding. But apparently it is not loaded. If i set the Date to new Date in ngOninit it works fine. I have checked that the ngOninit runs through and it does but still the values are undefined. I have also tried to load the data in the parent component and pass it on as a property binding (@Input) and i get the same result.

Now the funny thing about all that is that this works fine for Android and Web but not for IOS.

So does anyone have experience with different behaviour of ngOninit or angular in general on IOS?

Comment: Update: i have updated the IOS version of my testing device, and this seemed to solve the problem.